# Calling onclickserver in html it doesn't fire any event

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm facing a problem. When calling an html input tag on C# it doesn't fire any event. Can you please give an advice on the below html code and c# code?

```
  <input type="submit" id="btnBeforeOk" runat="server" name="btnBeforeOk" value="Login"   onserverclick="BtnBeforeOk_ServerClick"  />


 protected void BtnBeforeOk_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Youhana";

                  }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with your button code  like this:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
     protected void BtnBeforeOk_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ....
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I try Also this method but invain to call

Comment: So you code looks exactly as you have it in the question?